# How to know syntax error from jQuery event, as below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I've a form id -> `id ='login-form'`

```js
$('#login-form').submit(function(evt) {
  $('#login-button').addClass('disabled').val('Please wait...');

  evt.preventDefault();
  var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
  postData.push({
    name: "csrf_test_name",
    value: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
  });
  var url = $(this).attr('action');

  $.post(url, postData, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.success === true) {
      window.location.href = '<?= base_url().'
      sijb / home '?>';
    } else {
      $('#login-button').val('Login').removeClass('disabled');
      $('#error-message').text('Username dan Password tidak cocok').show();
    }
  }, 'json').error(function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

});
```

Comment: Add more information  on you OP

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try to remove line break from here at first:

```
 window.location.href = '<?= base_url().'
  sijb / home '?>';
```

to that:

```
 window.location.href = '<?= base_url().' sijb / home '?>';
```

Comment: So, I helped you to solve the syntax error issue, but I know nothing about your app and couldn't help you to find out what is the login issue. Give a little bit more information about your app. An just test every step of login proccess - check if you send the correct data and so on. I can do nothing now to solve that, sorry)

Comment: thank you for your answer,
i have found the problem, after i debug it turns out the function mcrypt_create_iv () is deprecated, and after i browse the php version in this codeigniter framework it takes a little library encryption for php 7.

Comment: and now i'm trying to downgrade php version. i hope is works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`if` block has some issue. Below is the fix I guess

```
if (result.success === true) {
      window.location.href = '<?= '+base_url()+'.sijb / home ?>';

      var delvar = '<? $_POST["del"]; ?>';
    }
```